# C# webservice and volley android

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asmx, android-volley

There are simple connections to consume a php page, but lack information on how to get consuming a DotNet webservice. This WebService returns a string in json and the problem is how to Volley call the webservice method. If you try to call a webservice with volley it shows only the xml configuration page, but is not the result of the function. With SOAP know we need to inform the url, namespace, method, if dotnet (dotnet = true) and everything, that is; with SOAP reported the method to be called. But how to do this in Volley? Is it not possible to work with volley and webservice in DotNet?

Comment: What kind of web service? ASMX or WCF? How is it configured?

Comment: hi, ASMX and subsonic framework

Comment: It may be possible to use Volley with a web service that uses SOAP, but maybe not JSON. Do you know for a fact that Volley can handle JSON?

Comment: Volley handles JSON. Make a post request with your parameters and if the answer is just a JSON it's really easy to use. The following tutorial may help you: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/